Circles to entirely cover off a square
We have a square with side length L.
We have many smaller circles with radius R.
What is the minimum number of circles we can place inside the square (having at least their centers within the square), overlap is fine, so that they cover off the entire area of the square?

The particular case we can test the function, which I was interested in is L=10, R=1
(Note the shape shown is not to scale).

I don't really have an idea on how to solve this yet, but one thing I was thinking of;
could we start by finding the lattice for a tiling of circles such that there are no uncovered gaps between the circles, and the bases of the lattice are maximal in length (I.e. the centers are as far apart as possible)? And then from that, try and remove a circle and perturb the centers to see if we can do it with 1 less circle? The problem is I don't know how to find the no-gap lattice with minimal distance between centers. I will update if I figure it out.

Is this a math question, or a Mathematica question?

It is well know that the hexagonal circle packing is the densest packing in 2D. But this leaves some holes between the circles. We can therefore try to put the circles closer so that the spaces disappear. I call this pseudo hexagonal. However, the condition that all centers lie in or on the square creates a problem, because, if we cover the square hexagonally, then some centers are outside. We may simply move the centers outside onto the border, but I have no proof this really gives the minimum number of circles.
For an example we choose a unit square and some radius. A pseudo hexagonal covering is then:
l = 1;
d = 0.27;
n1 = Ceiling[l/d];
off = ((n1) d - l)/2;
grid = Flatten[
   Table[d {i + If[OddQ[j], 1/2, 0] , j /2 } - off, {j, 0, 2 n1}, {i, 
     0, n1 - If[OddQ[j], 1, 0]}], 1];


If we now move the centers outside the square onto the border by: grid = {Clip[#[[1]], {0, l}], Clip[#[[2]], {0, l}]} & /@ grid:
l = 1;
d = 0.27;
n1 = Ceiling[l/d];
off = ((n1) d - l)/2;
grid = Flatten[
   Table[d {i + If[OddQ[j], 1/2, 0] , j /2 } - off, {j, 0, 2 n1}, {i, 
     0, n1 - If[OddQ[j], 1, 0]}], 1];
grid = {Clip[#[[1]], {0, l}], Clip[#[[2]], {0, l}]} & /@ grid

Graphics[{Point[grid], Circle[#, d/2] & /@ grid, 
  Line[{{0, 0}, {1, 0}, {1, 1}, {0, 1}, {0, 0}}]}]
Graphics[{Point[grid], Circle[#, d/2] & /@ grid, 
  Line[{{0, 0}, {1, 0}, {1, 1}, {0, 1}, {0, 0}}]}]



Thanks @Daniel Huber : is it giving the count of circles as output also?  ....I will study the solution in a bit when I get some time

I did not output the count, but this would simply be the number of points in grid.
